# How to make a value with thousand separator (like 0 000,0) in VBA (Excel, PowerPoint)

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, powerpoint

trying to formating double values for pasting it in presentation. For this i need to present values in custom format like 1 234,0.

I have tried using Format Function:
`VAL_PRODUCT = Format(iCell.Value, "# ###.#"`
With decimal everything okat, but there is no space between thousands and hundreds. There also no commas and number looks like 1234,0.
What I can do with it inside VBA?

Comment: So is this in Excel VBA, or PowerPoint? And is VAL_PRODUCT a Variant, Double, or String?  I just tried `Format(myDouble, "# ###.#")` and I got `1 234,5` (since my regional settings include a comma as decimal separator).

Comment: Try `Debug.Print Replace(Format(1234.5, "# ###.#"), ".", ",")` if a comma is the decimal separator in your regional setting.

Comment: Paul, Taller, macro in Excel, but I am pasting text in PPT. VAL_PRODUCT dim as double, I have no idea why, but using debug.print i got correct format, however, the problem still here:
`VAL_PRODUCT = Format(iCell.Value, "# ###.#") Debug.Print.VAL_PRODUCT`
I have 123,4, but in case of 
`Debug.print  Format(VAL_PRODUCT , "# ###.#")`
I have 1 23,4 in Immediate Window

Comment: Nobody knows what's the value of `iCell.Value`. Please use `Dim VAL_PRODUCT as String`. The return value of `Format` is a string. You don't need using Format twice.

Comment: Set the numberformat of the cell itself before giving it the value. As taller said (and me getting reminded yesterday), Format returns a Variant(String) but if your numberformat is general, it'll just read it as a normal number without showing you the correct result in the cell.